# Getting list of values from an entity in code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, loops, nsarraycontroller

I've got an `entity` called **clients** and an `NSArrayController` called **clientsController**. In my **clients** entity I have an attribute called **clientCompany**.

What is the most straightforward way of programmatically getting a list of each **clientCompany** while running a loop (so that code can follow on from each discovered **clientCompany**)? I'm not sure whether I should be accessing the array controller or the managed object in this case.

I've tried:

```
for (NSDictionary *key in clientsController) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [key objectForKey:@"clientCompany"]);
}
```

with no luck, but I think I'm way off on that. I've also tried printing the arrangedobjects of the array, out of curiosity, but it prints empty:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [clientsController arrangedObjects]);
```

**clientsController** has been initialised and accessed elsewhere in the program so I thought it would be straightforward but I'm very new to all this. Thanks.

---

**Update**

---

I've had a small bit of success going the `NSManagedObjectContext` route and trying `NSFetchRequest`. Requesting `ObjectAtIndex:0` I can now print the first **clientCompany** string to the console. I just need to be able to pull all them out in a loop but the hard part is done (I hope).

Comment: I've got a couple questions about your setup. Does clientsController contain client objects or client company objects? Also, what exact part of clientCompany are you trying to print?

Comment: An entity I have called **clients** has various attributes, none of which are called clients but one is called clientCompany. An `NSArrayController` I have is the object controller for clients through IB bindings. So by default clientCompany is a key value for the clientControllers managed object. I hope that makes sense because I'm not confident in my definitions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *clientsMoc= [clientsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Clients" inManagedObjectContext:clientsMoc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *items = [clientsMoc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];
NSInteger *counter;
counter = 0;
for (NSString *s in items) {
    NSManagedObject *mo = [items objectAtIndex:counter];  // assuming that array is not empty
    id value = [mo valueForKey:@"clientCompany"];
    NSLog(@"a value is %@", value);
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```